# Random permutations generation with non-repeating values at each index

Tags: algorithm, math, random

There was one problem:

Given a natural number sequence S of size n, [1,2,3,4....n], the task is to generate n **random** permutations but the catch is that the values shouldn't repeat at any index among all permutations.

For example, given n=3, S=[1,2,3], the possible result can be

1.[3,1,2]

2.[2,3,1]

3.[1,2,3]

Output like below is not acceptable as permutation 1 and 3 have same second value as 1

1.[3,1,2]

2.[2,3,1]

3.[2,1,3]

Another restriction was this needs to be solved with O(n) space complexity.

Comment: And what's your question about this? How is this related to programming?

Comment: Add your current approach as well

Comment: A simple rotation will suffice, given that there are no repeats in the original number sequence.  Each output is the previous out[ut shifted by one.

Comment: What distribution do you need to achieve in your randomness? Do you need to generate uniformly from the solution space? Does the support need to be the entire solution space?

Comment: As you can see from the duplicates, the main thing is to know that this kind of permutation is called a "derangement". That's easy to search for.

Comment: By randomness I only meant there is no way to pre-determine what sequences will be resulted, and in what order.

Comment: @rici thanks, that term will help!

Comment: Adding to my previous comment: if you want randomness then first do a systematic row-by-row rotation to get an n x n grid.  Then randomly shuffle the columns in the grid, followed by a random shuffle of the rows.  That will preserve the properties you want while appearing random.